# Cordova/ionic app for smart tv

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, samsung-smart-tv, android-tv

I developed an Ionic app for android and ios, but now i need to use the same app code for smart tv, to generate one apk compatible with android phone, tablet and tv.

Samsung gives an [SDK with eclipse and emulator](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Devtools/Sdkdownload) but after import the android project it return a lot of errors all in angular files

> Syntax error on token "finally", Identifier expected   ng-cordova.js
>
> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable ng-cordova.js
>
> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable angular.min.js
>
> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable angular.js
>
> Duplicate case angular-ui-router.min.js
>
> Syntax error on token "finally", Identifier expected   angular.js
>
> Syntax error on token "finally", Identifier expected   ng-cordova.js
>
> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable angular.js
>
> Duplicate case angular-ui-router.min.js
>
> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable ionic.bundle.min.js
>
> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable angular.min.js
>
> Duplicate case angular-ui-router.min.js

Can I use the same project to build an android tv/samsung smart tv app?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This has been ask for Apple TV also. There seems to be a real disconnect with this question, because the last I recall a Phone is not a TV.

Comment: your answer puzzles me. I'm wondering about the reuse of code from a project done for android phone, for android tv.

Comment: Yep. A phone is not a TV. How do you expect there to be code reuse? In spite of other speculation you read, while it is possible -- it is a division of systems. Past efforts to use a common code base have resulted in disaster. Beyond perhaps the UI, code reuse will be limited - AT BEST.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be possible to get the Android app you created for smartphones or tablets to run on Android TV devices, such as Sony and Philips TVs from their 2015 ranges or Google's Nexus Player. However, you will need to modify the user interface and controls of your app to work with a d-pad remote control, instead of touch or mouse.

Samsung's TVs do not run Android. Instead their 2015 models are based on Tizen. You might be able to modify the web part of your Ionic app to run on that platform, but I would not expect that to work without modifications either.

Comment: Thank you! That make me an idea of the situation

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend start with a clean Javascript project, as with angular.JS, proactor.JS or ember.JS for example.
I personally like yeoman with angular, as it comes with the gulp, grunt task and its easy to develop.
After having your project working on a normal browser you can then start to export to other devices using PhoneGap, Cordova or even Samsung.

For Samsung don't waste your time with the old SDK, you can only publish TIZEN and its late 2015 devices, and ill say 10% of the 2015 devices- I personally don't like samsung, support its a joke, the mess they have In House its a big Joke, running a system for 1-2 years and then changing them its another Joke, people are better buying a cheap android TV or an Apple TV.

Samsung sucks.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Right now the project stopped, but i'll continue with this later this year. Thanks again

Comment: Confirmed: samsung sucks

Comment: So what do you do with Samsung Smart TVs then? :(

Answer (score 1):

Ionic app builded for Android applications supports Android TV.

Also you can create separated Tizen project with web (html, css, js) architecture. Use iframe in that tizen project and you can use your app in Tizen platform. But for good navigation you need use CAPH lib.